# Solving Modular System with 2 different Moduli

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Is there any way to solve for $a$ and $b$ in:

$$ a*b          \equiv  s_0 \mod  r_0             $$

$$ a - b - a*b  \equiv  s_1 \mod ( r_0 - 1)  $$

I have the values of $r_0$, $s_0$, $s_1$ and would like to find the values for $a$, $b$? The $*$ is just normal integer multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the second equation as
$$(a+1)(b-1) = ab + b - a - 1 \equiv -s_1 - 1 \mod (r_0 - 1) $$
Take any $x,y,z,w$ such that

$$x y \equiv s_0 \mod r_0$$

$$z w \equiv -s_1 - 1 \mod (r_0-1)$$.

Since $r_0$ and $r_0-1$ are coprime,  we can find $a$ and $b$ such that:

$$a \equiv x \mod r_0$$

$$b \equiv y \mod r_0$$

$$a \equiv z-1 \mod (r_0 - 1)$$

$$b \equiv w+1 \mod (r_0 - 1)$$.

Then these satisfy your equations.

EDIT:
For example, if $r_0 = 5$, $s_0 = 1$ and $s_1 = 2$,
you want $x y \equiv 1 \mod 5$ and $zw \equiv -3 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.
One possibility (there are many) is $x \equiv 2 \mod 5$, $y \equiv 3 \mod 5$, $z \equiv 3 \mod 4$, $w \equiv 3 \mod 4$.  Then
using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $a \equiv 2 \mod 20$ and $b \equiv 8 \mod 20$.  And indeed
$ab \equiv 2 \cdot 8 \equiv 1 \mod 5$ and $a-b-ab \equiv 2 - 8 -2\cdot 8 \mod 4$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Connect the steps. Thanks.

Comment: How many equations of this type would I need to get a unique solution for $a,b < r_0$?